# Удаление первого (единственного) коммита

Tags: git

Подскажите, как удалить commit, если он один.

Ветка master, создал один коммит и хочу удалить его.

Answer (score 2):

[подсказывают](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32765827/4827341), что удалить первый и единственный коммит можно, например, так:

```
$ git update-ref -d HEAD
```

---

хотя, вероятно, более естественным будет пересоздание самого хранилища (т.е., содержимого каталога `.git`):

```
$ rm -rf .git && git init
```